# How to format a date with formatDate on angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I try to get this format with angular [`formatDate`](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

```
"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

So I use this code

```
formatDate(
  '2019-01-01',
  'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z',
  'en-US'
)
```

The result is `2019-01-01T00:00:00+0200`

Z is replaced by the zone. There is a valid way to make the format I need ?

Comment: Yes there most probably is. But what exactly do you want? What did you try? What didn't work? Please be more specific with your question

Comment: @cloned All what you say is wroten in my post. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question. Someone was able to solve it, for me it was not clear what you meant. That's why I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `Z` as a string or it will be treated as per [this](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options)

```
"yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00\'Z\'"
```

---

```
formatDate(
  '2019-01-01',
  "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00\'Z\'",
  'en-US'
)
```